# Why are my tables not listed in the Redshift pg_table_def system table?

Tags: amazon-redshift

So I have created some tables:

[image]

But they are not listed when I query pg_table_def?  Any ideas appreciated.

[image]

Comment: does your `search_path` contain the proper schema? `show search_path;`

Comment: search_path is $user, public

Comment: It works...I added the schema to the search path.  Is search path a session level variable or can it be added to permanently?

Answer (score 1):

"For modifying the search path permanently on your cluster , please modify the search_path parameter in the parameter group that is currently associated with your cluster.
For step by step instructions please refer to the link below :-

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-parameter-groups-console.html
"

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=131150

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but in case there is anyone like me looking for the straight answer on the command line:

Set the `search_path` parameter to include the schemas you want.
*For a single session*, it's `SET search_path TO my_schema, my_second_schema [...]` for as many schemas as you like.
To set the search path *permanently for one user*, it's
`ALTER USER my_user SET search_path TO my_schema, my_second_schema [...]`.